# Visual Studio Load Test Agent Weighting

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I have a questions about Visual Studio 2013. We're running load tests with agents. In total, we have 5 agents and 1 controller. In the agent properties (from the Manage Test Controller option), I have set the weighting to 15 for each agent. This totals 75 - so does that mean that the controller handles the rest?

The documentation is a little vague as it suggests that if you make one 20 (e.g. A) and another 40 (e.g. B) that B will run double the load of A. However I am not sure how this works when we have 5 agents set to 15?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The weights are just specifying ratios. If all the values are the same (ie 15 in your example) then each agent will get the same load.

Suppose you want to run a test with 300 simulated users with your 5 agents each having a weight of 15. Then each agent gets approximately (300*15)/(5*15) users, ie 60. The "approximately" is added because other values may not divide nicely with integers.

Suppose instead that the 5 agents have weights of 7, 11, 13, 17 and 19. Then the 300 simulated users will be spread as approximately 31, 49, 58, 76 and 86, respectively.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243155.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695837.aspx) for more details.